# Error: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting this error when attempting to set the Uri to the SSRS 2014 Report Server Uri. Here's the code where the error occurs.

```
mReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New System.Uri("http://MONROE:80/ReportServer_SQL2014")
```

This is on a new ASP.NET 4.0 web application that I am testing before release. The exact same code executes fine under the current production version of this web application which is .NET 3.5.

I can't see what's dangerous about this URL. I'm wondering if it could be something else that's causing the error, however, this appears to be the offending line of code because if I comment this out, the page loads normally (albeit without rendering the report).

Any thoughts??

---- UPDATE - 5/3/2018

Removing the :80 (not really needed) _ from the report server name solved the issue with the illegal path name, but now I'm getting another strange error.
[image]

The really strange thing is that this same web application and report viewer works fine on my development machine using IIS Express. Also, this report URL works fine in the production version under ASP.NET 3.5.

Any ideas on what path or file name is the concern here, because http://MONROE/ReportServer_SQL2014 is definitely not 248 characters in length!

Here's the code for the Application_BeginRequest procedure...

```
   Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
    ' This solves a vulnerability issue
    ' Microsoft Knowledge Base (KB) article 887459, "Programmatically Checking for Canonicalization Issues with ASP.NET,"
    If (Request.Path.IndexOf(Chr(92)) >= 0 Or
      System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Request.PhysicalPath) <> Request.PhysicalPath) Then

        Throw New HttpException(404, "Not Found")
    End If
    ' The following line must be restored when moving to production on a site with a secure certificate
    If ((Not HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection) And (Not HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)) Then
        Response.Redirect("https://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
    End If
```

Comment: Maybe the new project it set to us https, and therefore it is warning you becuase of the http?

Comment: Does the error occur when **setting** the URL, or does it occur when **calling** it?

Comment: Maybe add `Uri.EscapeDataString("http://MONROE:80/ReportServer_SQL2014")`.

Comment: Also, I can't say for sure that the code line listed above is the culprit because I believe I have gotten past that point. I think the error is sourced somewhere within SSRS now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is caused due to underscore (_) in the report server url.

Can you try adding the following code in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and the error went away, but it was replaced by "The given path's format is not supported."

Comment: I'm' wondering if it's the :80? I probably don't need to specify port 80 in this instance.

Comment: I pulled out the :80 but I'm still getting the error. Something else in http://MONROE/ReportServer_SQL2014 is prompting this error.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot and exception stacktrace the error seems to be originated from line 145 in Global.asax.vb file inside Application_BeginRequest method. Can you put a breakpoint and step through the code to troubleshoot.

Comment: The problem with that is that this error occurs on a production server so I don't have access to the debugger. I don't get this error on my development workstation.

Comment: Ok! So can you share code of Application_BeginRequest method?

Comment: I will add this as a code block to me original post (above).

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetFullPath is causing this error. Based on the suggestion [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception.aspx) try adding the following in your web.config:

<runtime> 
   <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false" /> 
</runtime>

Comment: Okay, tried adding this setting and I'm still getting the PathToLong error. May be time to open up a support issue with Microsoft.